# Wrong version of libcrypto

Tags: ubuntu, libcrypto

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit, and I'm trying to make something that requires libcrypto. I already have libssl-devel installed. However, it's finding the wrong version. I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8: File format not recognized
/usr/bin/ld:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc:2: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [P11Sample_x64] Error 1
```

I did a locate on libcrypto and found multiple versions:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
/usr/lib/vmware-ovftool/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
```

Looks like it's trying to use /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 which is a directory, not a file. How do I point it to the correct version (probably /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so or /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.0.9.8)

Thanks!